# Power series is conditionally convergent for at the most two values of x

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I come across this result:

> Any power is conditionally convergent for at most two values of $x$, the endpoints of its interval of convergence.

If it is so then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a power series$$\tag{1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$$which converges at some point other than $a$, but does not converge everywhere. So, it converges at some $x_0$ with $x\neq a$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(x_0-a)^n=0$ and it can be deduced from this that if $|x-a|<|x_0-a|$ then the series $(1)$ converges absolutely. Therefore, if $|x-a|>|x_0-a|$, then the series $(1)$ diverges. The statement that you mentioned follows from this.

Comment: Would anyone know of a power series that converges at some point and diverges at some other point having the same modulus ?

Comment: @JamesWell $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n$ diverges at $1$ and converges at $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $=r>0$.

If $r= \infty$, then the power series converges absolutely in each $x \in \mathbb R$.

Let $r< \infty$ and $I=(x_0-r,x_0+r)$. Then the power series converges absolutely in each $x \in I$.

Therefore there are at most two points in which the power series converges but not absolutely: $x_0-r$ amd $x_0+r$.